# Outlook 2007: software to remove duplicate emails in inbox

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pop3

My POP3 server is giving me a hard time, and has decided to download my entire inbox again, so now have duplicates of all my messages.  Any software or addons (free, please) that I can use to remove these dupes?

OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Outlook Duplicate Items Remover](http://www.vaita.com/ODIR.asp), it is free.  The down side is it is slower than I like, I have a very large PST file.